# Pytorch nn.Conv1d outputs different results than Tensorflow 2.1 tensorflow.keras.layers.Conv1D

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am trying to preproduce a seq-to-seq model that i have created in PyTorch to Tensorflow 2.1.
The Pytorch model works perfectly, but the output of the same model implemented in tf 2.1 are very bad. After a lot of debugging i found out that the bad results may occur because of the difference in implementation between nn.Conv1d and tf.keras.layers.Conv1D.

In my Pytorch model, i use:

```
  self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=ic, out_channels=oc, kernel_size=k, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
```

In my Tensorflow model, i use:

```
  self.conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding='same', use_bias=use_bias)
```

Does anyone know how can i produce the same results in tf, as in my Pytorch code? Is there any other function that can help me? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Your padding is different between the two for starters. In tensorflow 'same' implies enough padding to ensure the output is the same size as the input. Padding 0 in pytorch doesn't pad so the output will be smaller than the input unless k=1.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
i have preprocessed the data in a way that the input to the Conv1D is the same both on Pytorch and Tf. Tf code runs, but the results are real bad.